# Setting extent to plot a certain country in Cartopy package, Python

Tags: python, cartopy, cartography

I am getting started with package Cartopy for Python. I would like to display the map of Hungary with the help of package Cartopy. I'm using the following code.

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def main():
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax.set_extent([20, 10, 20, 30], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())

    ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAND)
    ax.add_feature(cfeature.OCEAN)
    ax.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE)
    ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS)
    ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAKES, alpha=1, color="blue")
    ax.add_feature(cfeature.RIVERS)

    plt.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

What I don't understand is how the coordinates in `ax.set_extent([5, 16, 46.5, 56]` work. These are the coordinates for Germany, I found them on the web. I've looked up the longitude/latitude for Germany, and these numbers in the code has nothing to do with them. I would be glad if somebody could explain these coordinates and give the coordinates for Hungary. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The image which can be created with the code below shows of longitude/latitued with negative/positive.  `ax.set_extent([x_0, x_1, y_0, y_1]` first defines the x parallel range and then the y parallel range.

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(18, 12))
map = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
grid_lines = map.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
map.coastlines()
```